# Metaprogramming in C++: check a condition on the elements of a vector and transfer to an unordered map

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

I start the question saying that I am quite new to C++ metaprogramming and I am trying to look back to my codes, trying to find a solution to transfer to compile time some task I am doing runtime. So, thank you in advance for your help, and I am sorry if the question appear stupid to you.

### Explanation of the task

I am trying to fullfill a simple task in C++, of iterating on a vector, check if the elements are positive and finally transfer the positive elements in a map.
In a "naive" way it would be:

```
    const vector<long> vec;
    unordered_map<long, long> dic;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (vec[i] > 0) {
            dic[i] = vec[i];
        }
    }
```

### Possible implementation

My idea was to try to avoid the branching, transferring everything at compile time, and hence to avoid the use of the `if`, by trying to use metaprogramming and templates. For this reason, inspired by [this article](https://bhilburn.org/using-c-templates-to-optimize-away-branches/),

- I created a template function for the `if` evaluation at compile time:

```
template<bool condition, typename typeA, typename typeB> 
void fill_value(typeA &A,typeB &B)
{
    if constexpr (condition){
        A=B;
    }
}
```

- I tranformed my loop in :

```
const vector<long> vec;
unordered_map<long, long> dic;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long element = vec[i];
        constexpr bool condition = (element>0); 
        fill_value<condition,long,const long>(dict[i],vec[i]);
    }
```

### Question

Clearly this version of the code does not compile because I am declaring as `constexpr` a statement that is not `constexpr`, coming from a vector that is only  `const`. So I would ask you:

- Is it possible in some way to change the implementation in a way that the `constexpr` is correctly declared?
- Has anyone a different implementation to propose?

Comment: You can't move any of this code to compile time.  `vector` and `unordered_map` both allocate memory, and that happens at run time.

Comment: I believe your compile-time ambitions end where `std::unordered_map` comes into play. I couldn't find anything `constexpr` qualified to insert something in the `std::unordered_map`... (even if you would replace the `std::vector` by something else).

Comment: If the original `vec` gets filled in at runtime then trying compile time meta programming is pointless.

Comment: Vector `vec` is not filled runtime, it is given as an input in the `main`

Comment: FYI: [Compile-Time Map - Static Hash Map at Compile Time](https://github.com/ChoppinBlockParty/ctm) or [boost::hana::map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html)

Comment: @albiremo That **is** runtime.

Comment: You may think about the metaprogramming something like a substitution of the macro of the C language. Maybe, you'll be easier to learn the subject of your question. The main aim of the templates and Co is to avoid of coding similar entities, but it isn't suitable to perform things you queried about. When you are writing a template, you say to compiler: "Thou is free to generate set of similar functions (or classes) for different cases".

Comment: @albiremo If the values aren't known until the program runs, then it is run time code.

Comment: If you replace the vector with an array or initializer_list, you could *maybe* avoid the check and just pass an initializer list to the unordered_map constructor. But that's the best you can do. The unordered_map will always do its stuff at runtime. Compared to the cost of building an unordered_map, saving a few cycles on the if statement is pointless

Comment: @Serge You are right, sorry.  Thank you for the hints anyways. I was trying in some way to reduce the cost, but as Homer said, maybe is better to rethink the structure of the code.